# How to assign unique value to rows if any column value is same in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I have 2 sas datasets. One dataset has clusters based on 5 column value. If any column is same between rows then those rows have same unique key. Similarly second dataset has similar cluster based on same columns. Now i have to merge these two datasets based on columns values and then assign unique key of any column match. 
Suppose 1st data has 1 cluster which has 5 rows and 2nd data has another cluster which has 2 rows. If any row matched between these 2 datasets then all 7 should have same unique key

Comment: A good question will describe what you have tried, what errors you are experiencing and sample data (not pictures) demonstrating the starting data and wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Vivek, you will probably want to learn about either `SET` statement to concatenate rows based on key, or `MERGE` statement to combine disparate columns based on key.  Your description, of "5 rows", "2 rows" and "all 7" suggests stacking.

```
data want;
   set
     dataset_one
     dataset_two
   ;
   by key1 key2 key3 key4 key5;
   if first.key5 then fiveLevelGroupId + 1;
run;
```